# Query hundreds millions rows using partial searches in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, large-data

Considering a simple database containing a table `foo (name text, description text)` and a table `bar (key text, other_info text)` which share a many-to-many relationship (`foo_bar (foo_id, bar_id)` ).

The fact is, I want to obtain `foo` rows when a `bar.key` contains a **partial pattern** for example `'a'` or `'1234'`. So basically I want a `JOIN` and a `LIKE '%a%'`. And it could be the end of my story...

However, my table `foo` contains 10 millions rows and queries take time... Moreover, the table will soon have **hundreds millions of rows**! In the production environnement, the database is read-only mode.

So I started thinking about materialized view as:

`foo_view (name text, description text, bar_key text)`

which saves me the `JOIN`.

And I started using `trigram indexes` to have faster partial matches, and it works.

But it's not enough...

I started thinking about `ARRAY` to saves me the `JOIN` *and* the `DISTINCT` part as

`foo_view (name text unique, description text, bar_keys text[])`

I used the `parray_gin` extension to have partial searches and indexes with arrays. For now, this is my faster solution.

But it is not enough... (for one million rows it's good but not for more...)

I started thinking about partionnement but with ten millions rows I don't see a significative difference...

My database is not a complex one and I can create as table/view as necessary. My problem is: **I will have to query hundreds millions of rows using a partial search and I can't manage to do it fast**.

I know that the hardware has a crucial part in performance, but that's not something I can change. Maybe I will later. But for now, my question is strictly software-side.

I need to know if the solutions I tried were good ones or if I missed something.

Comment: Have you considered using ElasticSearch?

Comment: Recent article written on doing full text search using native PostgreSQL: https://blog.lateral.io/2015/05/full-text-search-in-milliseconds-with-postgresql/ Pretty interesting stuff.

Comment: @MattBall No. I am not limited to PostgreSQL but I don't know ElasticSearch and consequently I don't know that it could be more appropriate. Do you think it is ? and why ?

Comment: @JNevill I thought that the full text search was using for search of words in big texts. In my case I search letters in a single-word key. I thought also that basically the full text search *removes* small noises like 'a' or 'e'. But in my case, I want to be able to search an 'a'. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Though not _exactly_ your use case, this might be interesting as well: http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html

Comment: Have you identified the bottleneck of each solution iteration ? Also, can you tell us more about your business case and query patterns ? In fact you (may) have many solutions left, but we need to take into account your use case. I assume you don't need to return or display hundreds of millions of results, so maybe there is an alternative solution that will emerge from this information

Comment: @ClémentPrévost I'm working with biological data and I'm creating an interface to query these data. Basically, a user will want to type an identifier or a part of it and will want to obtain the list of genes matching his search. The result could contain only one row but could also contain millions of rows (e.g. *I want every gene from the human specie*).

Comment: Ok, so you have a huuuuge list of tagged genes. Do you have some sort of pagination to iterate over those results ? Or these million of rows are dumped all at once to the client for further processing maybe ?

Comment: @ClémentPrévost My pagination system is made during the client-side processing. At the beginning I paginated server-side using LIMIT and OFFSET but since my queries are long, it was taking time to change the pages. So now it's client-side.

Comment: Well, the core problem with pagination might be the underlying (and necessary) ordering. Ordering a huge amount of rows is a pain. What are your requirements about ordering ? Also, what's your page size and expected response time ?

Comment: This is called infix pattern search, by the way. You might want to look into pg_trgm indexes, but I suspect the size penalty may be untenable.

Comment: I finally switched to ElasticSearch and it's incredibly powerful. Off course this is a non-PostgreSQL solution to a PostgreSQL problem but I'd take it since it is far more efficient than expected :D